# kubectl apply -f -f deployment.yaml give aws error

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, deployment

while running kubectl command i am getting aws error.
kubectl apply -f -f deployment.yaml
error: unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": Get "https://*****.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 2

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused due to the version of aws i was having. Moving to a higher version of aws(2.11.12 ) solved the issue for me.